# PyCharm の画面でファイル名の箇所が赤くなっているのは何を表していますか？

Tags: python, pycharm

この赤くなっているprivate_diary ディレクトリの中身のファイルが突然無くなってしまいました。
赤くなっているのと関係がありますか？ある場合どうすれば良いでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ディレクトリーがバージョン管理されたディレクトリー内にあって、追跡されていない場合（Unkownなステータスの場合）に、通常その色(画像が見づらいですが、赤というより赤茶色ですかね？)が表示されます。

Gitなどでバージョン管理していれば、Gitの履歴から復元することができますが、その状態だと履歴にないかもしれないので、Pychramのローカルヒストリーを確認してみるといいと思います。対象のディレクトリーを右クリックして、「Local History」>「Show History」でローカルヒストリーが表示されます。削除前のファイルがあれば、「Revert Selection」で復元できるかもしれません。